# Java error message "... has private access in ..."

Tags: java

I have run into a situation when writing code in Java. The error mentions that in my code `newLine() has private access in PrintWriter` I have never gotten this error and it worries me as I cannot understand why `newLine` would be `private` to my variable `PrintWriter`

Below will be my error messages and part of my code where this issue comes from.

Errors:

```
:75: error: newLine() has private access in PrintWriter
                        savingsFile.newLine();
                                   ^
:77: error: newLine() has private access in PrintWriter
                        savingsFile.newLine();
                                   ^
:96: error: cannot find symbol
        while((str1=savingsFile.readLine())!=null){
                               ^
  symbol:   method readLine()
  location: variable savingsFile of type Scanner
3 errors
```

Code:

```
    public static void writeToFile(String[] months, double[] savings) throws IOException{
    PrintWriter savingsFile = null;
    try {
        savingsFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("E:/savings.txt", true));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //code to write to the file and close it
    int ctr = 0;
    while(ctr<6){
            savingsFile.write(months[ctr]);
            savingsFile.newLine();
            savingsFile.write(savings[ctr]+"");
            savingsFile.newLine();
            ctr = ctr + 1;;
        }
        savingsFile.close();
    }

   public static void readFromFile(String[] months, double[] savings) throws IOException{
    String str1, str2;
    Scanner savingsFile = null;
    try {
        savingsFile = new Scanner(new File("E:/savings.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //code to read the file, load data in the array and close file
        str1 = savingsFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str1);
        int ctr = 0;
        while((str1=savingsFile.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
        savingsFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PrintWriter does not have a public newLine() method ([see the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)). Just write a newline character `"\n"` to make a new line, or call `println()` with no arguments.

Scanner does not have a `readLine()` method.  You probably meant `nextLine()`

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time out of your day to help me out! :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `newLine()` is a private method in PrintWriter what means that you can't invoke it externally from some other class that instantied PrintWriter as object.

Comment: how do i make it not private?

Comment: @Sutdent_Sequej, you can't make it not private. It's an internal method of a standard Java class, so you can't change its visibility. Use Jim Garrison's suggestions.

Comment: alright thank you very much for helping me out today!